# Should I use UITableView or UICollectionView when building a chat app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to build a chat app like the native Messages app/Whatsapp.

The design is a little bit different than the native chat bubbles (rectangle messages view instead of bubbles) but I guess the basics are the same. Of course the messages should start from the bottom of the screen like any chat app, and in the bottom there should be a "new message" textField.

Should I use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` for this purpose?

Thank you!

Comment: UICollectionView will be better for future customization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just finished shipping a chat app and went through this exact question when building the architecture. This isn't a hot take.

I made the mistake at first to go with `UITableView` only to realize halfway that UICollectionView is way more powerful. (`UICollectionView` even has a tableLayout if you want to use it this way).

I realized this after studying the other chat libraries available like `JSQMessagesViewController`, `MMTextureChat`, `MessageKit` etc.

UITableView is good but soon enough you'll run into performance and customization issues like I did.

As for showing the messages from the bottom, the trick is to flip the view. That way when you call `insert(atIndexPath:)` the item shows up at the bottom.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use `UICollectionView`

Comment: How can I flip the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: if you flip the view you still gonna run into other problems too, you will also need to flip your cells, I've been using the UITableView for chat for a year now and I haven't seen any performance issues at all it's very smooth